# Merge two columns into one column

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to merge two columns into one in the result set. How can i achieve this in SQLite?

```
Query:
SELECT Table3.Id [Col1], Table4.Id [Col2] FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.ExtId
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Id = Table3.ExtId
LEFT JOIN Table4 ON Table2.GroupId = Table4.Id
```

```
Col1|Col2
NULL|101
NULL|102
201 |NULL
NULL|103
202 |104
```

Expected:

```
Col
101
102
201
103
202
104
```

I want to avoid using UNION ALL because that will mean i have to have two subqueries.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid UNION? did you compare the performance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers